# Need to validate an attribute is below of an other attribute using selenium cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I need to validate an attribute (`attributeName`), which is immediately below another attribute (`attributeName1`) in an application using Selenium-Cucumber. Please help me with the logic.

How I can validate? I am trying to use the below code but it's not helping.

```html
@When("^Verify attribute name \"([^\"]*)\" is  below  \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void verify_attribute_name_is_below(String attributeName, String attributeName1) throws Exception {
     try{
      CreateLoanUtils.navigateToAttribute(attributeName);
      String attributeLocator = ScenarioParamManager.get("attributeLocator");
      List<String> expectedElements = Arrays.asList(attributeName1,attributeName);
      List<String> actualElements = new ArrayList<String>();
      WebElement parentElement = CoreUtils.Get_Element(attributeLocator);
      List<WebElement> elements = parentElement.findElements(By.xpath("../../..//span[@class='cxhelp']"));
      for(WebElement temp: elements){
       if(expectedElements.contains(temp.getText()))
       actualElements.add(temp.getText().replace(":", ""));
      }System.out.println(actualElements);
      CoreUtils.Capture_Screen_Shot(attributeName1);
      CoreUtils.Capture_Screen_Shot(attributeName);
      int comparison = Collections.indexOfSubList(expectedElements,actualElements);
      
      if(comparison != -1){
       ReportingUtils.Add_Step("Options in the correct order ", Status.PASS, true);
       ReportingUtils.currentScenario.write("Options in the correct order ");
      }
      else{
       ReportingUtils.Add_Step("Options in the incorrect order ", Status.FAIL, true);
       Assert.fail("Options in the incorrect order");
       ReportingUtils.currentScenario.write("Options are  in incorrect order ");
      }
      
     }catch(Exception e){
      ReportingUtils.Add_Step("ERROR:  Options are  in the incorrect order ", Status.FAIL, false);
      Assert.fail("ERROR:  Options in the incorrect order");
     }
    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Some example HTML would be very helpful as well.

Comment: Also.. when you say "below", do you mean below in the DOM or below on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the WebElement's Location field.

```
 if (topElement.location.y < botElement.location.y){
      //Do Something
 }
```

Comment: This may or may not work depending on the positioning of the element which may not correspond to its position in the DOM.

Comment: I thought he wanted to see which element was above the other. If he wants to see what comes first in the dom wouldn't searching the text of the html be easier than using selenium?

Comment: You may be right... I took "below" as below in the DOM and not below on the screen. I reread the question and I'm still not sure. It would need clarification by the OP.